# Tomcat catalina log file doesn't contain any data

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 5. Since two months the catalina log file doesn't contain any data.

I checked the `server.xml` and `logging.properties`. All seem normal.

Comment: Have you checked catalina.out? Could be a file permission issue. Alternatively, you can run Tomcat in the foreground so that the logs are printed to console - you will probably see a message telling you what the issue is

Comment: You mean, Permission issue..What type of permissions? Where I need to check? Can you explain in more details?

Answer (score 0):

When I add this in my config file, those are printing.

```
<category name="your.class.package">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
```

Thanks